# discord.py - Need help to use cog_command_error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, runtime-error, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot with python using the rewrite version of the discord library.
I want to create a **specific event handler for every single cog** and I've found the method '**cog_command_error**' by scrolling through the documentation.
The problem is that I can't use it due to an error, I have tried to interpret it but without any actual results.
I think it's about passing a parameter as an argument to an error, but I'm not sure; I'm not an experienced person in this ambit, indeed, I have googled for hours looking for an example that actually works, but all the samples I've found and tried out don't.
if I use on_command_error it works, but it handle errors from others cogs and I don't want this to happen.

Excuse me for my bad english but I'm italian.

**Here it this the code:**

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', case_insensitive=True)

load_dotenv(os.path.join('bot.env'))
TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

async def cog_command_error(ctx, error):
    print("\nsalve\n")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('You need to specify a module')
    else:
        raise error

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if extension.casefold() == 'all':
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                try:
                    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}') #Cut last 3 char (.py)
                except:
                    pass

        await ctx.send('Loaded all extensions')
    else:
        try:
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
            await ctx.send(f'Loaded {extension} extension')
        except:
            await ctx.send("Extension already loaded or doesn't exist")

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}') #Cut last 3 char (.py)

client.run(TOKEN);
```

**And the error:**

```
Ignoring exception in command load:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
    File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in invoke
        await self.prepare(ctx)
    File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 751, in prepare
        await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
    File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 670, in _parse_arguments
        transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
    File "C:\Users\Manuel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 516, in transform
        raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a command-specific error handler you're gonna want to use a decorator to identify that the function is for that specific command, for example:

```
@load.error
async def load_error(ctx, error):
    print("\nsalve\n")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('You need to specify a module')
    else:
        raise error
```